# Ruby: Grab a single JPG image from an authenticated IP CAM and save to a file

Tags: ruby, ip-camera

Using ruby, what is the easiest way to grab a single JPG image from an IP camera that requires authentication and write the image to a file?  For example an IP camera that has uses a URL:

*http://192.168.69.81/cgi/jpg/image.cgi*

I don't need to perform any manipulation of the image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the remote location and write the file as a jpeg image called image.jpg:

```
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://192.168.69.81/cgi/jpg/image.cgi'

open(url, :http_basic_authentication => ['username', 'password']) do |f|
  open('image.jpg','wb') do |file|
    file.puts f.read
  end
end
```

Comment: I ended up with the method using open-uri, but added authentication

Comment: I accepted your answer.  Unfortunately, I don't have a high enough "reputation" to up vote.      If you are curious here is my project: https://github.com/elvisimprsntr/siriproxy-ipcam

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start(url, port) do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/image.cgi')
  req.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
  response = http.request(req)
  open("image.cgi", "wb") do |file|
    file.write(response.body)
  end
end
```